# How can i add if statement in email code

Tags: twig

I have this code in email, is it php?

How can i add "if statement" here?

I need only attachment|file_url where attachment.file.originalName like "%sheet%"

```
{% for attachment in order.attachments %}
{{ attachment|file_url }}
{{ attachment.file.originalName }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is twig probably

Comment: "_I need only attachment|file_url where attachment.file.originalName like "%sheet%"_" Would probably fit better in your query/controller/model, not in your template/view file.

Comment: i am just a user, not admin

Comment: So contact your admin or it support.

Comment: Admin gave me only one code example for free

Comment: `{% for attachment in order.attachments if 'sheet' in attachment.file.originalName %}` - I just gave you one comment for free then

Comment: i have voted your answer, thank you, it works!